# apt upgrade gives errors

Tags: apt, upgrade

I've been unable to upgrade for some time now due to errors. Here is the latest output.

Please note that I have tried to uninstall QGIS, so I'm not sure why `apt update` is still checking it.

My goal is to upgrade to 22.04

```
$ sudo apt update 

Hit:2 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease          
Ign:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish InRelease             
Get:1 https://ubuntu.qgis.org/ubuntu impish InRelease [2’719 B]        
Ign:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates InRelease     
Err:1 https://ubuntu.qgis.org/ubuntu impish InRelease   The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY D155B8E6A419C5BE  
Ign:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports InRelease  
Ign:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security InRelease  
Err:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish Release   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]  
Err:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates Release   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]  Err:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports Release   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]  
Err:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]  Reading package lists... Done  
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://ubuntu.qgis.org/ubuntu impish InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY D155B8E6A419C5BE  
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish Release' does not have a Release file.  
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.  
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details. 
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates Release' does not have a Release file.  
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.  
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.  
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports Release' does not have a Release file.  
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.  
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.  
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release' does not have a Release file.  
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.  
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.10
Release:    21.10
Codename:   impish
```

Comment: Upgrade to 22.04 from what? Are you using 21.10? That reached end of life this July so you won't be able to upgrade this way.

Comment: I added the ouptut of lsb_releases  -a to the question, but your assumption is correct. Does this mean that my only option is to reinstall?

Comment: That didn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Then please [edit] your question and add _the complete, exact_ steps you took to try it.

Comment: Ubuntu 21.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/07/19/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-end-of-life-reached-on-july-14-2022/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades  *Your issue is the EOL release - refer to EOLUpgrades link for fixing your sources to cope with EOL status*

Comment: FYI:  You can re-install (esp. desktop systems!) without loss of data & having *manually installed* packages (*if from Ubuntu repositories and available for new release*) automatically re-installed; so *upgrade via re-install* is actually faster than an in-place *release-upgrade*... but if using 3rd party packages you're best using *release-upgrade*... You didn't say if desktop/server, but for server *release-upgrade* is much much safer/better!

Comment: Please don't forget you're using *impish* and not *groovy*, thus you need to adjust for your system... ie. *groovy* is *impish* on your current system, and where the *groovy* system was moving to *hirsute* in the duplicate system (ie. g to next letter h!) you're currently *impish* so need to go to next letter *j* which is called *jammy*...   Adjust answer for your situation!  ie. my first comment post included a link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/JammyUpgrades  which is what you want; except you need the extra step required in EOLUpgrades as you're very late.

Comment: if you just want to upgrade release, just use `sudo do-release-upgrade`

Comment: Thanks for everyone's comments and suggestions. In the end, I became uncomfortable with the all of the random attempts to get this to work so I just backed my my data and reinstalled 22.04.